# SharePoint Development Advice

Tags: sharepoint-online

As a SharePoint developer What I need to be aware of in the development world for  SP 2016 and SP online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **First, you should start learning the following:**

**The SharePoint Framework (SPFx)** is a page and part model that enables client-side development for building SharePoint experiences. It facilitates easy integration with the SharePoint data, and provides support for open source tooling development. To start learning SPFx check [Welcome to the SharePoint Framework Developer Preview!](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki)

**Note:** The SharePoint Framework is till now not available for SharePoint On-Prem

---

**PNP** stands for Developer Patterns and Practices that is initiative provides samples and documentation to help you to implement typical customizations for Office 365 or for SharePoint (Online and on-premises) based on your functional requirements.

PNP can be run also on ShareePoint On-Prem but you'll need to make some changes to the solution that you want to run. for more details check [How do I run the Office 365 Developer Patterns and Practices against SharePoint 2013 On Premises](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/wiki/How-do-I-run-the-Office-365-Developer-Patterns-and-Practices-against-SharePoint-2013-On-Premises)

To start learning PNP check [Office 365 development and SharePoint patterns and practices solution guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/office-365-development-patterns-and-practices-solution-guidance)

---

**CSOM** stand for the client-side object model (CSOM) that provides client-side applications with access to a subset of the SharePoint Foundation server object model, including core objects such as site collections, sites, lists, and list items.

The CSOM actually consists of three distinct APIs—the

1. ECMAScript object model,
2. the Silverlight client object model,
3. and the .NET managed client object model

To start learning CSOM check [Using the Client Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx)

---

**Also, you should be aware of**

- HTML/JavaScript
- OData
- OAuth
- REST endpoints
- New client and server APIs
- SharePoint Add-ins
- Client-side rendering
- Remote event receivers

All details mentioned at [What's new for developers in SharePoint?](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/what-s-new-for-developers-in-sharepoint)

**You should also have a strong knowledge to use the below Development tools**

- Napa Office 365 Development Tools
- Visual Studio
- SharePoint Designer

For more details check

- [Office 365 development and SharePoint patterns and practices solution guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/office-365-development-patterns-and-practices-solution-guidance?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [SharePoint development overview](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-development-overview)
- Or watch this good video [What's New for Developers in SharePoint 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuNzniUKNhc)

Comment: **Update:**  SharePoint Framework web part is now available for SharePoint Server 2016 with Feature Pack 2, For more details, check https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/16/sharepoint-framework-for-sharepoint-server-2016/