# What is SharePoint Spfx? Will it override SharePoint app development and server object model?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

What will be impact of new Spfx development model over older SharePoint object model.

Answer (score 11):

**What is SharePoint SPFx?**

`The SharePoint Framework (SPFx)` is a page and part model that enables client-side development for building SharePoint experiences. It facilitates easy integration with the SharePoint data, and provides support for open source tooling development. To start learning SPFx check [Welcome to the SharePoint Framework!](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki)

---

**Will it override SharePoint app development and server object model?**

The SharePoint Framework is till now not available for SharePoint On-Prem.

The **SPFx** is preferable because:

- It runs in the context of the current user and connection in the browser. No iFrames.
- The controls are rendered in the normal page DOM.
- The controls are responsive and accessible by nature.
- There is a life cycle that the developer is involved in.
- It’s not just render, but load, _serialize _and deserialize, configuration changes, etc.
- It is framework agnostic – You can use any browser framework that you like – React, Handlebars, knockout, angular – take your pick.
- The tool chain is based on common open source client development tools like npm, TypeScript, yeoman, webpack, gulp, etc.
- Performance is key.
- SPFx client-side solutions that are approved by the tenant administrators (or their delegates) can be used by end users on all sites – even self service created sites like teams, groups, personal, etc.
- Can be deployed in both classic web part and publishing pages as well as the modern pages.

For more details check

- [Why SPFx](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Why-SPFx)
- [Welcome to the SharePoint Framework!](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki)
- [SharePoint Development Advice](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219213/sharepoint-development-advice/219228#219228)

Comment: **Update:**  SharePoint Framework web part is now available for SharePoint Server 2016 with Feature Pack 2, For more details, check https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/16/sharepoint-framework-for-sharepoint-server-2016/

Answer (score 6):

Web Parts deployed as full trust solutions were cool, except that they required admin access to the server and they enabled one developer to easily take down the server.

Web Parts deployed as sandbox solutions solved the first issue, and partially addressed the second. But code still ran on the server, and functionality was somewhat limited.

App Parts (add-ins, aka app model) solved the above by running code on a different server, but app parts work via iframes, which are a pain.

SPFx solves the above, by allowing JavaScript to run in the context of the page, but not in an iframe. So everything's perfect now. Almost.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't. There are still many scenarios such as elevating privileges or implementing long-running operations, that require the SharePoint add-in model. Also, if you want to isolate your solution from other elements on the page, SharePoint add-ins might be a better fit than SharePoint Framework solutions. Think of the SharePoint Framework as yet another tool in your toolbox that you can, but don't have to use.

Answer (score 0):

Add-Ins are great if you're integrating with applications outside of SharePoint. Outside of iFrames, the full screen Add-In/App model allows you to carry over SharePoint's design and theming over to another full-screen experience. We use it heavily over here.